# Regex finding all commas between two words

Tags: regex

I trying to clean up a large .csv file that contains many comma separated words that I need to consolidate parts of. So I have a subsection where I want to change all the commas to slashes. Lets say my file contains this text:

`Foo,bar,spam,eggs,extra,parts,spoon,eggs,sudo,test,example,blah,pool`

I want to select all commas between the unique words bar and blah. The idea is to then replace the commas with slashes (using find and replace), such that I get this result:

`Foo,bar,spam/eggs/extra/parts/spoon/eggs/sudo/test/example,blah,pool`

As per @EganWolf input:
How do I include words in the search but exclude them from the selection (for the unique words) and how do I then match only the commas between the words?

Thus far I have only managed to select all the text between the unique words including them:
`bar,.*,blah`, `bar:*, *,blah`, `(bar:.+?,blah)*,*\2`

I experimented with negative look ahead but cant get any search results from my statements.

Comment: What did you try and where is the problem?

Comment: @EganWolf I looked ad countless cheat sheets and regex generators, I did not post my regex's here because they are all general ones like \b,\b or bar,.*,blah... not really helpful. How do you exclude keywords that you are searching by?

Comment: Can you use a split operation of all commas and then join the targeted elements with /? What OS is this happening on?

Comment: Linux: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Notepad++, you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\bbar,|\G(?!^))\K([^,]*),(?=.+\bblah\b)`
- Replace with: `$1/`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # start non capture group
    \bbar,      # word boundary then bar then a comma
  |             # OR
    \G          # restart from last match position
    (?!^)       # negative lookahead, make sure not followed by beginning of line
)               # end group
\K              # forget all we've seen until this position
([^,]*)         # group 1, 0 or more non comma
,               # a comma
(?=             # positive lookahead
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newlie
    \bblah\b    # word boundary, blah, word boundary
)               # end lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Foo,bar,spam/eggs/extra/parts/spoon/eggs/sudo/test/example,blah,pool
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for this detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will capture the minimally required text to access the commas you want:

```
(?<=bar,)(.*?(,))*(?=.*?,blah)
```

See [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ABVZVU/1).

If you want to replace the commas, you will need to replace everything in capture group 2. Capture group 0 has your entire match.

An alternative approach would be to split your string by comma to create an array of words. Then join words between bar and blah using `/` and append the other words joined by `,`.

Here is a PowerShell example of split and join:

```
$a = "Foo,bar,spam,eggs,extra,parts,spoon,eggs,sudo,test,example,blah,pool"
$split = $a -split ","
$slashBegin = $split.indexof("bar")+1
$commaEnd = $split.indexof("blah")-1
$str1 = $split[0..($slashbegin-1)] -join "," 
$str2 = $split[($slashbegin)..$commaend] -join "/"
$str3 = $split[($commaend+1)..$split.count] -join ","
@($str1,$str2,$str3) -join ","

Foo,bar,spam/eggs/extra/parts/spoon/eggs/sudo/test/example,blah,pool
```

This could easily be made into a function with your entire line and keywords as inputs.

Comment: Great answer and thank you. I marked the other as correct because by doing it via text editor its more general. +1